# Django Template only Accesses One Value from the Model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a variety of classes, two of which have a structure as such:

```
class SomeClass(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, db_index = True, blank=True)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=60, db_index = True, blank=True)
    year = models.DateField(db_index = True, blank=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

        class Meta:
            ordering = ('name',)
```

The view is as follows:

```
def home_page(request):
    classList = SomeClass.objects.values('name')
    someInstance = classList[0]
    return render_to_response("base.html", {"classList":classList, "someInstance":someInstance})
```

The template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <title> Title </title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "styles/base.css" %}" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="banner">
        BANNER TEXT
    </div>
    <div id="banner-wrapper">
    </div>  
    <div id="sidebar">
        CLASS
        <ul>
            {% for someClass in classList %}
            <li><a href="/CLP/{{class.name}}">{{class.name}}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        </div>

    <div id="someClass">
        {% block class %}

        <h2> {{someInstance.name}} </h2>
        <br>
        <h4> {{someInstance.value}} </h4> 

        {% endblock class %}
    </div>
</body>
```

In my template, I can readily access `{{ someInstance.name }}` for either, but I do not get values for if I try `{{ someInstance.value }}` or the like. I have verified that the values exist, and that the models are populated using the django admin page, as well as the shell. What else can I try?

I am on using django 1.6

Comment: You'll need to show the view and the template.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the template in, it keeps formatting as html. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only fetching the `name` property in your view:

```
def home_page(request):
    classList = SomeClass.objects.values('name')
    ------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This is why the other properties of your object are not available in your template.

Also, your template - not sure if its a copy paste problem:

```
{% for someClass in classList %}
    <li><a href="/CLP/{{class.name}}">{{class.name}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Here I believe you need `{{ someClass.name }}`

Also, you have an indentation issue in your models:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
```

The `class Meta:` should be at the same level as the `def`, and `__unicode__` should return a unicode object:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode(self.name)
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed that. Still getting used to it. Thanks